# preg_match: All characters must match

Tags: php, regex

I have an user input which gets checked if the chars are on the whitelist.

My regular expression:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\s\$%\^&\*\(\)\=\:\;\+\°\´\[\]\{\}\§\"\'\ß\ä\ö\ü\%\.\,\>\<\|\€]+$
```

My code part:

```
$check = preg_match($pattern, trim($input));
```

Now, when the `$input` variable has for example the value `abc²³`, the input gets blocked. But when it has the value `abc²³def`, the content won't get blocked.

How can I check **every** character of a string?

Answer (score 3):

You simply forgot the start of string anchor: `^`

```
^[\p{L}\d_~\-!@#\s$%^&*()=:;+°´\[\]{}§"'%.,><|€]+$
```

I also simplified the regex. Note that I replaced `A-Za-Zßäöü` with `\p{L}` which will accept letters from any language.

Comment: It worked. The problem is, that the user will buy a lettering in a certain font and I can't gurantee that all languages work in this certain language.

Comment: @wernersbacher could you expend on that (preferably by editing your question)? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: The solution works fine. It's just about your simplification. You said it will accept letters from ANY language. The problem ist, that the user will something with a certain font and that font doesn't support all characters from any language.

Comment: The font is irrelevant here, this only deals with Unicode character categories. `\p{L}` will accept any characters from the categories starting with *L* on [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm). You decide if it's what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You have to anchor the regex at the begining:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\s\$%\^&\*\(\)\=\:\;\+\°\´\[\]\{\}\§\"\'\ß\ä\ö\ü\%\.\,\>\<\|\€]+$
```

You also may simplify a bit:

```
^[\w~\-!@#\s$%\^&*()=:;+°´\[\]{}§"'ßäöü%.,><|€]+$
```

Or, even, using unicode properties:

```
^[-\p{L}\p{N}_~!@#\s$%\^&*()=:;+°´\[\]{}§"'%.,><|€]+$
```